# Adding new rows and tds using Jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add new row to the table using Jquery method.

The td's are too huge and need to split to multiple lines to insert it..The last line is failing without adding any rows (but no js errors). How can I do this?

```
$('#div3-table').append('<tr><th>SERVER NAME</th><th>EDIT</th><th>STATUS</th></tr>')
$('#div3-table').append('<tr><td>APPLIANCE</td><td><input type=\'radio\' id=\'applradio\' name=\'applradio\' checked/></td>')
$('<td>').append('<td><label id=\'DISPLAYAPPL\' for=\'success\'>NOT CONFIGURED</td></tr>')
```

Comment: `$('<td>')` create a td element, but you are never appending it to anything, so of course "nothing" happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can break it up easily using jQuery. The key is to use jQuery method chaining like so:

```
$('#div3-table')
.append($('<tr/>')
   .append('<td>...</td>')
   .append('<td>...</td>')
   .append('<td>...</td>'));
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QTKVB/